# Download Java Application using JNLP with single domain and multiple IPs

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

We have a Java Application having multiples jar and launch over JNLP using a URL. Whenever we change the IP behind the URL  our all jars download again.

What information on client machine are checked to download the jars?

Comment: I thought it was just the URL string and the last-modified dates of the jars. Are those dates somehow changing as you migrate to the new IP? Also, what is the `codebase` entered into your JNLP file? I'm assuming that is the URL and not IP.

Comment: there is no modification in jars so the last-modified dates are same. Yes, the codebase values is URL.